# Silverlight: How to do this data binding?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, xaml

I have a control that displays information about an `Foo` object. I am doing data binding just fine. However, I have an `AutocompleteTextBox` in this control that needs an `ItemsSource`. The data exists in my app, but there's no reason for it to be available on each instance of `Foo`. What is the preferred pattern here for dealing with it?

I have a static method on a different class that will return the list I want - `Bar.GetNames()`. Is there some way I can call that from the XAML? Or do I need to use a `StaticResource`?

I'm using Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to do it in codebehind, probably in AutoCompleteTextBox.Loaded event handler. Something like:

```
void AutoCompleteTextBox_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((AutoCompleteTextBox)sender).ItemsSource = Bar.GetNames();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could go a few different ways...

You could create a custom `AutoCompleteTextBox` which has the listing embedded (pulled from some static repository internal to the app, etc...) within the control.

You could have the property on Foo that goes to a service or other middle man within the app to retrieve the data from a single location.

You can reference the static resource within XAML by...

`Text={x:Static namespace:type}`

...where namespace is the residing namespace of your type defined in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot reference static property in Silverlight XAML.

I would suggest something like FooViewModel:

```
class FooViewModel: AnyBasicViewModelAround {
     public Foo Model {get; set; }
     public ItemNames : IList<ItemEntry> { get { return Bar.GetNames(); }}
}
```